# How can i achieve mobile number length limitation and allow only number?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i am trying mobile number maximum length should be 10 digit. The given code is working properly but when i give input type number the validation is not working. Please help me to resolve

```
<!--Mobile input-->
 <div class="col">                   
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server">Mobile no</asp:Label>                              
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" class="form-control" maxlength="10"            runat="server" placeholder="Mobile number"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMobile"
    ErrorMessage="Mobile numbeer is required." ForeColor="orange"  Display="Dynamic">   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revphone" runat="server"  ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{10,15}$" ControlToValidate="txtMobile" ErrorMessage ="Maximum 10 digit is requirred" ValidationGroup="reg" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="orange"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</div>
```

Comment: `^[0-9]{10,15}$` means it should contain only numbers and have a min length of 10 and a max length is 15, what is your real expectation, bit unclear your issue

Answer (score 1):

To restrict users from entering more than 10 digits and only for numbers, you can write your code as,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server" maxlength="10" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
```

If you need to do it using `RegularExpressionValidator`,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server" maxlength="10"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPhone" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMobile" ErrorMessage="Enter 10 digit mobile number" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{10}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: This regex will force to enter *exactly* 10 digits

Comment: Hi sir, maxlength property or using RegularExpressionValidator i achieve the limitation in textbox but i also need that mobile number textbox allow only number . I also tried textmode="number" property. when i give this property maxlength or rRegularExpressionValidator  it does not work, the textbox allow n number of characters, please help me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Only a numerical value with Minimum 4 and Maximum 4 digits lengths is required

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPhone" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSurveyYear" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Min 4 & Max 4 digits required" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{4,4}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```